# How can you convert "view engine" value in expressjs to render html instead of jade?

Tags: node.js, express

This is my current code:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

I want to convert the jade files to html and render html instead. I tried substituting 'jade' with 'html' but that didnt' work.

Comment: The code above tells express to use the file extension `.jade` when you omit them.  See http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings

Comment: you want to render HTML ? but express+jade generates html for you. the client will always get html.

Comment: Not just render - I want to write in HTML, because I dont know jade and I dont want to spend time learning it.

Comment: If you're finally going to use html files, you can use EJS instead of Jade. http://embeddedjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`res.sendfile`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile) to serve HTML files:

```
res.sendfile('path/to/html/file.html');
```

(to convert any existing Jade files to HTML, you can install Jade globally using `npm install jade -g` and use the command line utility `jade` to convert them)

But that doesn't "render" anything, because rendering assumes some form of templating engine. If you want to use a different templating engine, perhaps one that *looks* more like HTML than Jade does, you can take a look at [`ejs`](https://npmjs.org/package/ejs) or [`swig`](https://npmjs.org/package/swig).

Also, instead of using `res.sendfile`, you can use the [`express.static`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html) middleware, which will serve any static files (like plain HTML, JS, CSS):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: I've read that this isn't cached and not best for production.

Comment: Static file serving can best be left to something like nginx, although Node can easily handle 1000+ requests per second like this.